# How can I display a random number - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I create an input with a random value?

For example:

I have 3 possibles values for a given input:

```
[ 'Value 1',
  'Value 2',
  'Value 3' ]
```

And I want one of these 3 values entered in the `<input>` randomly and automatically.

Comment: use `.val()` to set the value then use an array then use a random number to get the random value then set that value in input

Comment: can you explain us exactly what you need ?

Comment: Can you add a little bit more code? For example the input element which you want to have the values assigned to

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
var x = Math.random();
var y;
if (x < 1/3)
    y = "VALUE 1";
else if (x < 2/3)
    y = "VALUE 2";
else
    y = "VALUE 3";
alert(y);
```

Assuming you want each of the values to be chosen with equal probability.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var randomvalue = ['one','two','three'];//set what values you want 

var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (2 - 1 + 1));//generate random number for index 
console.log(index)
//Note:set 2 as max and 1 as min because in array i set only 3 values so the number will be random from 0-2 where 0 is first item because it is index
$("#test").val(randomvalue[index])//setting the random value as input text
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="test"/>
```

1. Using `.val()` to set the random value
2. Using array to have selection for the value for input
3. Lastly generating random whole number to be use as index

Comment: Your random generator is not right. If you want random numbers from 0 to 2, you need to multiply by 3. Also you could make it generic `var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * randomvalue.length);`